# -q command in terminal, PyQt5 on Python2.7

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pyqt5

I have spent the last hour or two trying to install PyQt5 for Python2.7. It is a pretty straight forward task, however I am running into an error following [this](https://gist.github.com/kilfu0701/47b74a17a70b43549985) github guide. So far, I have been able to get through to line 21. Here I run into an error, 
`configure.py: error: no such option: -q`. 
I have typed the code exactly and cannot find any information online about what -q is. Or what it does. Here is my full terminal input/output:

```
$ python configure.py -q /Users/development/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/bin/qmake -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ --sip /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip
This is SIP 4.16.7 for Python 2.7.10 on darwin.
Usage: python configure.py [opts] [macro=value] [macro+=value]

configure.py: error: no such option: -q
```

Thank you in advance.

Updated with --help

```
Zacharys-MacBook-Pro:sip-4.16.7 development$ python configure.py --help
This is SIP 4.16.7 for Python 2.7.10 on darwin.
Usage: python configure.py [opts] [macro=value] [macro+=value]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -k, --static          build the SIP module as a static library
  -p PLATFORM, --platform=PLATFORM
                    the platform/compiler configuration [default:
                    macx-g++]
  -u, --debug           build with debugging symbols
  --sip-module=NAME     the package.module name of the sip module [default:
                    sip]
  --configuration=FILE  FILE contains the target configuration
  --target-py-version=VERSION
                    the major.minor version of the target Python [default:
                    2.7]
  --sysroot=DIR         DIR is the target system root directory
  --no-tools            disable the building of the code generator and the
                    installation of the build system [default: enabled]
  --use-qmake           generate qmake .pro files instead of Makefiles

  MacOS X Configuration:
    --arch=ARCH         build for architecture ARCH
    --deployment-target=VERSION
                    set the value of the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
                    environment variable in generated Makefiles
    -n, --universal     build the SIP code generator and module as universal
                    binaries
    -s SDK, --sdk=SDK   the name of the SDK used when building universal
                    binaries [default: MacOSX10.13.sdk]

 Query:
    --show-platforms    show the list of supported platform/compiler
                    configurations
    --show-build-macros
                    show the list of supported build macros

 Installation:
    -b DIR, --bindir=DIR
                    where the SIP code generator will be installed
                    [default: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/
                    Versions/2.7/bin]
    -d DIR, --destdir=DIR
                    where the SIP module will be installed [default:
                    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages]
    -e DIR, --incdir=DIR
                    where the SIP header file will be installed [default: 
                    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2
                    .7/include/python2.7]
    -v DIR, --sipdir=DIR
                    where .sip files are normally installed [default: /Sys
                    tem/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/s
                    hare/sip]
```

Comment: `python configure.py --help`?

Comment: @Coal_ I updated it with help. I am mostly ignorant when it comes to binding and installation processes. I dropped out of second year CS. :| Would I use -use-qmake?

Comment: @Sleepy-Z. The install script you linked to is totally broken. Before line 21, it needs to download the [pyqt5 tarball](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), unpack it, and then cd into the resulting source directory. The reason why you're seeing that error, is because the script is stuck in the **sip** source directory (which has already been built). The error and help output is therefore all from the **sip** configure.py, rather than from pyqt5. See [the pyqt5 install docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source).